# Multiple Inheritance functions

Tags: c++, inheritance

EDIT : I am trying to create a customer class, however having problems with the functions.

These are the instruction to follow : Derive a new class  - Customer Class (Inherits from Savings – savings inherits from bank account)
Write a customer class.  Customer Class has the following new attribute
Customer Name

Any direction on how to fix my functions will help

```
#include "BankAccount.h"
#include "SavingsAccount.h"
#include <iostream>

class Customer : public SavingsAccount, public BankAccount {
protected:
    string CustomerName;

public:
    string getCustomerName();
    void setCustomerName(string);

    void WithdrawSavings(){ Customer c; c.BankAccount::balance(); }
    void DepositSavings(double);

    Customer(){
        CustomerName = "";

    }
};
```

Comment: There's just too many obvious problems here. You have more fundamental problems than just with this compilation error. This question is not salvageable...

Comment: Are you sure a `Customer` _is a_ `SavingsAccount` and a `BankAccount`??

Answer (score 1):

The use of inheritance here is muddled. It should look more like this:

```
class BankAccount {
    // whatever
};

class SavingsAccount : public BankAccount {
    // whatever
};

class Customer {
    SavingsAccount savings;
};
```

This says that a `SavingsAccount` **is** a `BankAccount`, and that a `Customer` **has** a `SavingsAccount`.

Comment: I wonder if the original post would have been better as `SavingAccount` + `CurrentAccount`.

Comment: @JoeS - post that as an answer. That way you can write actual code instead of somewhat imprecise descriptions.